# Google Domains DNS: MX Record Already In Use

Tags: dns, google-domains

I'm trying to add a second MX record with a different priority by get this "record already in use" error.
[image: adding second mx record fails]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [webmasters.se] or [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the MX record and create a new one, but press the `+` button to see the create more records.

[image: mx record plus button]